# PHP - correctly set cookie parameters (expire) using header() - not set-cookie()

Tags: php, magento, cookies, header, hhvm

A site we are using is running an older HHVM version.
Looking at the documentation of PHP function [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), there is two signatures for parameters.

To summarize the issue why I cannot use `setcookie()` is because this version does not use the `$options` array available of PHP7.3.   When trying to use some of the alternative solutions by concatenating `samesite` to `path` will *crash HHVM.*   Using this alternate method using normal PHP works correctly as expected.

*There seems to be a slight difference between HHVM behaviour here with cookies compared to PHP*.

So this question is about *header()* and not about *setcookie()* because I can't use it, there are slight difference in how HHVM (the version running) handles cookies.

NOTE:  *This is a Magento 1 site --- and upgrading to HHVM 3.30+ breaks **everything** so that is also not an option - I have tried this already*.

So I managed to set the cookie using `header()` function by concatenating all the properties.

```
header('Set-Cookie: frontend=abcdef; expires=188888888; path=/; domain=www.mydomain.com; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

Result in Response Headers:

```
frontend=abcdef; expires=188888888; path=/; domain=www.mydomain.com; Secure; SameSite=None
```

Set-Cookie documentation refers to this:

> You may notice the expires parameter takes on a Unix timestamp, as opposed to the date format Wdy, DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT, this is because PHP does this conversion internally.

#### Question

- How to correctly set the **expires** value, as I am creating a *raw* header instead of using `setcookie()` the UNIX timestamp will be in the cookie as shown above, in other words `setcookie()` converts the UNIX timestamp internally...
- I have tried the following as well - but I am not sure this is correct for `expires` or not:  **What format is required?**

Sample:

```
php -a

php > $b = 3600 * 24 * 365;
php > $c = time() + $b;
php > echo $c;
1643355613
php > $dt = new DateTime();
php > $dt->setTimestamp($c);
php > echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H-i-s');
2022-01-28 09-40-13
```

*Not entirely sure that format will be correctly used by expires*

This question relates to issues about sessions not working in some cases, but I will keep these questions seperate.

Comment: _“What format is required?”_ - did you not just quote exactly that from the manual on setcookie …?

Comment: Maybe the question should be cleared up, which formats are allowed, which are not.... and _how to_ set them corectly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date

Comment: Thank you, this cleared it up in the `/Date` url:

"Greenwich Mean Time. HTTP dates are always expressed in GMT, never in local time".

I will investigate how to convert DateTime to the GMT timezone in PHP

Comment: Note that HHVM 3.30 fell out of support *over a year ago* https://hhvm.com/blog/2018/12/17/hhvm-3.30.html and it sounds like you're on a version even older than that! You are running a version of HHVM with *multiple unpatched security vulnerabilities*. You really, really should upgrade to a modern version of PHP 7 (since HHVM no longer supports vanilla PHP code like Magento). You are putting your customers at risk by running such out of date software!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to answer how to create a *raw set-cookie using **`header()`** function*.

Because `setcookie()`automatically changes the **timestamp into the formatted string**, this conversion has to be done ourselves.

The  [Mozilla Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes) says this:

> The maximum lifetime of the cookie as an HTTP-date timestamp. See Date for the required formatting.

The [Mozilla Headers Date format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) shows the format required:

```
  Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT
```

To create a properly formatted date string for `set-cookie` using `header() function`:

```
// Assume current time + one day
$expires = time() + 60 * 60 * 24;
$dateTime = new DateTime();

// Set the timestamp
$dateTime->setTimestamp($expires);
// Set the timezone using a new DateTimeZone instance
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
// Print the format.
// This format based on PHP DateTime formats - the 'e' switch adds the time zone at the end.
$format = 'D, d M Y H:i:s e';
$expiresText = $dateTime->format($format);

// Set the raw header with expires text (encode if needed)
header("Set-Cookie: cookieName=cookieValue; expires=$expiresText; samesite=None; Secure");
```

This should give a `set-cookie` that has the Date formatted as required.